# Unable to decrypt the encrypted sms (encrypted in 2.2 os )in Android...(trying to decrypt in 2.3 os)

Tags: java, android, encryption, aes

I am able to encrypt an SMS and send it from one simulator (Android 2.2) to another.
On the receiving end I am able to do the decryption successfully. But the problem is if do the encryption in one OS version (i.e Android 2.2) and trying to decrypt in another OS version ( Android 2.3 ) i am getting 'Bad padding exception'. I checked that i used the same key on both ends. 
The code is shown below

```
public class ED {


    private  String Key;

        public ED() {
            Key = "abc12";   // Assigning default key.
        }

        public ED(String key) {
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
            Key = key;

        }



        public String encrypt(String toEncrypt) throws Exception {
            byte[] rawKey = getRawKey(Key.getBytes("UTF-8"));
            byte[] result = encrypt(rawKey, toEncrypt.getBytes("UTF-8"));
            return toHex(result);
        }



        public  byte[] encrypt(byte[] key, byte[] toEncodeString) throws Exception {

            SecretKeySpec sKeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(key, "AES");
            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, sKeySpec);

            byte[] encrypted = cipher.doFinal(toEncodeString);

            return encrypted;
        }

        private  byte[] getRawKey(byte[] key) throws Exception {

            KeyGenerator kGen = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");
            SecureRandom sr = SecureRandom.getInstance("SHA1PRNG");
            sr.setSeed(key);
            kGen.init(128, sr);
            SecretKey sKey = kGen.generateKey();
            byte[] raw = sKey.getEncoded();
            return raw;

        } 

    /************************************* Decription *********************************************/

            public String decrypt(String encryptedString) throws Exception {

                byte[] rawKey = getRawKey(Key.getBytes("UTF-8"));
                System.out.println("Decrypted Key in bytes : "+rawKey);


                System.out.println("Key in decryption :"+rawKey);


                SecretKeySpec sKeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(rawKey, "AES");
                Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
                cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, sKeySpec);
                byte[] decrypted = cipher.doFinal(toByte(encryptedString));
                System.out.println("Decrypted mess in bytes---------->" +decrypted);
                return new String(decrypted);
            }






            public String toHex(byte[] buf) {
                if (buf == null)
                    return "";
                StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer(2*buf.length);
                for (int i = 0; i < buf.length; i++) {
                    appendHex(result, buf[i]);
                }
                return result.toString();
            }
            private final String HEX = "0123456789ABCDEF";
            private void appendHex(StringBuffer sb, byte b) {
                sb.append(HEX.charAt((b>>4)&0x0f)).append(HEX.charAt(b&0x0f));
            }

            public byte[] toByte(String hexString) {
                int len = hexString.length()/2;
                byte[] result = new byte[len];
                for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
                    result[i] = Integer.valueOf(hexString.substring(2*i, 2*i+2), 16).byteValue();
                return result;
            }

    }
```

And I am using sendTextMessage() function to send an sms. I read that encryption/decryption doesn't depend on OS but in this case that is not true. Am I missing any important things while configuring the Cipher (in AES) ? Please let me know.

Comment: Not an answer, just an idea: Have compared the output/input (what you send vs. what you receive) - like, hashed it and compare the result?

Comment: If you don't mind performance and Java 1.5 and greater compat I always use sb.append(String.format("%02X", b & 0xFF)). I'm not even sure if that last 0xFF (to make it possitive) is even necessary.

Comment: Similar problem: [javax.crypto working differently in different versions of Android OS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6316225/javax-crypto-working-differently-in-different-versions-of-android-os/6467548#6467548)

Comment: Thank you very much Robert. That link solved my problem. The problem comes with SecureRandom key generation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's setSeed(). It does not do what you think it does: it just adds the entropy of the given seed to the underlying algorithm. You'll probably find out that it returns somehthing different on both platforms. SHA1PRNG *is* a pseudo random function, but if it is already seeded, it's likely to return different results.

Comment: You are correct Mr.Owlstead. The proble is with SecureRandom() generation, setSeed(). You told "You'll probably find out that it returns somehthing different on both platforms" and that is correct.

Comment: So the best way to solve the problem is use another method to generate a key. For more information c this lik (if any one need the solution)  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6316225/javax-crypto-working-differently-in-different-versions-of-android-os/6467548#6467548

Comment: Mr. owlstead, I like that :). The key generators listed in the given link should be ok. If you like the answer, don't forget to accept it.

Answer (score 0):

If the problem is in the key length, you could derivate a key from your password, instead of using it directly. You could use a Hash (like SHA-1, MD5, etc) and crop it to the correct size (128, 192 or 256 bits), or use `PBEKeySpec` instead of `SecretKeySpec`.

That to remove problems with the key length. If the padding problems were in the plaintext, I suggest you to use `CipherInputStream` and `CipherOutputStream`, which are more programmer-friendly to use than `Cipher.doFinal`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with SecureRandom generation. It is giving different results on different platforms. It's because of a bug fix on line 320 (in Gingerbread source) of SHA1PRNG_SecureRandomImpl.java in the engineNextBytes() method where

```
bits = seedLength << 3 + 64;
```

was changed to

```
bits = (seedLength << 3) + 64;
```

Use SecretKeyFactory() to generate a Secure key instead of secure random.

```
public class Crypto {

Cipher ecipher;
Cipher dcipher;

byte[] salt = { 1, 2, 4, 5, 7, 8, 3, 6 };
int iterationCount = 1979;

Crypto(String passPhase) {
    try {
        // Create the key
        KeySpec keySpec = new PBEKeySpec(passPhase.toCharArray(), salt, iterationCount);
        SecretKey key = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBEWITHSHA256AND128BITAES-CBC-BC").generateSecret(keySpec);
        ecipher = Cipher.getInstance(key.getAlgorithm()); 
        dcipher = Cipher.getInstance(key.getAlgorithm());

        AlgorithmParameterSpec paramSpec = new PBEParameterSpec(salt, iterationCount);

        ecipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key, paramSpec);
        dcipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key, paramSpec);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
        //Toast.makeText(this, "I cought ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }


}

public String encrypt(String str) {
    String rVal;
    try {
        byte[] utf8 = str.getBytes("UTF8");

        byte[] enc = ecipher.doFinal(utf8);

        rVal = toHex(enc);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
        rVal = "Exception Caught "+e.getMessage();
    }
    return rVal;
}


public String decrypt(String str) {
    String rVal;
    try {
        byte[] dec = toByte(str);
        byte[] utf8 = dcipher.doFinal(dec);

        rVal = new String(utf8, "UTF8");

    } catch(Exception e) {
        rVal = "Error in decrypting :"+e.getMessage();
    }
    return rVal;
}

private static byte[] toByte(String hexString ) {
    int len = hexString.length()/2;
    byte[] result = new byte[len];
    for ( int i=0; i<len; i++ ) {
        result[i] = Integer.valueOf(hexString.substring(2*i, 2*i+2), 16 ).byteValue();

    }
    return result;
}
private static String toHex(byte[] buf) {
    if (buf == null)
        return "";
    StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer( 2*buf.length);
    for ( int i=0; i<buf.length; i++) {
        appendHex(result, buf[i]);

    }
    return result.toString();
}

private final static String HEX = "0123456789ABCDEF";

private static void appendHex(StringBuffer sb, byte b) {
    sb.append(HEX.charAt((b >> 4) & 0x0f)).append(HEX.charAt(b & 0x0f));
}


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't rely on `KeyGenerator` to generate the same key just because you seeded the RNG the same way. If you are pre-sharing a key, share the key, not the seed.

You should also specify the encryption transform completely: "AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding"

Finally, ECB mode is not secure for general use.

See [another answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/992413/3474) for an example to perform encryption correctly with the JCE.